# Embed JasperReports Server directory into web application

Tags: directory, jasper-reports, embed, jasperserver

I have many reports on *JasperReports* and they are embedded into our web app using iframe API. Some of the reports are scheduled to run everyday and store the generated files on *JasperReports*.

I want to embed the folder location on our web application so that User can see the report file listing in the web application.

```
http://${url}/jasperserver-pro/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=/${location}/&reportUnit=/${location}/${reportName}&fromDate=&toDate=&decorate=no&j_username=${username}&j_password=${password}
```

The above link is being used to access report but I am not able to figure how to do the same for directories.

Please let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give users the access to all of the reports in your repository, you can pass the directory location into your URL instead of passing in the path to your report

Comment: I tried that but It is not working. I have a report which runs every night at 2 and stores generated report which is in PDF format into a directory. I want to make that directory accessible to user using iFrame.